# need help creating tabs with svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to make some tabs which looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuBZS.jpg) . At first I tried to do it with plain `css` by creating a triangle with the border trick but it seemed imposible making the gray border . I want to do it using `SVG` but i've never worked with those before and I'm a little bit stuck . Can someone point me in the right direction ? .Thanks

```css
.c-tabs {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.c-tabs:after,
.c-tabs:before {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.c-tabs:after {
  clear: both;
}
.c-tabs__item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 22px 0;
  color: #0b5d98;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: nexaBlack, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.c-tabs__item svg:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.c-tabs__item svg:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  right: -23px;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}

// .c-tabs__item :after {
//      content: '';
//      position: absolute;
//      width: 20px;
//      height: 100%;
//      top: 0;
//      right: 0;
//      border-left: 30px solid transparent;
//      border-top: 30px solid transparent;
//      border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
//      background: #fff;
//      z-index: 2;
////      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px $light-base;
//    }
    
// .c-tabs__item :before {
//      content: '';
//      position: absolute;
//      height: 100%;
//      width: 20px;
//      height: 100%;
//      top: 0;
//      right: 0px;
//      border-left: 33px solid #e9e9e9;
//      border-top: 33px solid transparent;
//      border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
//      z-index: 1;
//    }

.c-tabs__item--active {
  background: #03bfd7;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #03bfd7;
}
.c-tabs__item--active:after {
  border-left: 30px solid #03bfd7;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-tabs">
            <div class="c-tabs__item c-tabs__item--active" data-tab="sumar">Pasul           1:sumar</div>
            <div class="c-tabs__item" data-tab="account">Pasul 2: înregistrare
            <svg width="100%" height="100%">
              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke-width="3px" stroke="red"></line>
              <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="100%" stroke-width="3px" stroke="red"></line>
             
            </svg>
            <svg width="23px" height="100%">
               <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="90%" y2="50%" stroke-width="2px" stroke="red"></line>
               <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="90%" y2="50%" stroke-width="2px" stroke="red"></line>
            </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="c-tabs__item" data-tab="shipping">Pasul 3: livrare</div>
             <div class="c-tabs__item" data-tab="review">Pasul 4: PLată</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: SVG is essentially just another type of image, which is not what you want here -- you want a solution in CSS. Also, asking to find "*a good course on svg*" is both highly subjective and off-topic. Please review the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for topics that are considered 'on-topic'.

Comment: ok ,we can forget about svg course. Why is an SVG solution not good here ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make those triangle shapes with SVG's instead of CSS you can make them in Sketch or Illustrator and export them as SVGs which you can then import into your project.

[Here](http://creativedroplets.com/export-svg-for-the-web-with-illustrator-cc/) is a guide on how to do it with Adobe Illustrator.

And [here](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/exploring-ways-to-export-clean-svg-icons-with-sketch-the-correct-way-752e73ec4694#.9jwmzm1al) is a guid on how to do it with Sketch.

Your workflow would be something like:

Step 1 - Make shape in Illustrator or Sketch

Step 2 - Export shape to SVG code

Step 3 - Import SVG code directly into project